# Rails filter data with multiple time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I want let my user to decide what time period does some **contents** can be present.

```
it's divide into two partial:
1.for date (like 2016,01,01~2016,12,20)
2.for hour (like 11:00~13:00)
```

there is multiple time period setting that user can add for their **contents**,
for example

- 11:00~12:00
- 17:00~19:00
- 2016,03~2016,07
- 2017,01,20~2017,01,22

how can I implement it? add a associated table with four time columns(start date, end date, start time, end time) for contents table?? or any helpful gem?

Comment: why you dont use datetime?

Comment: plz explain more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm on my phone but will update this answer when I get home.  This is basically what you're looking for but the window of data is between certain days and not dateTime so you'll have to add hours/minutes etc.  It's also using the SimpleForm gem however you can easily modify the form to jive with rails regular form_for instead.  Use the jquery datepicker since it's awesome and easily configurable. Key thing to note is that your input for the jquery datepicker is a string so youll have to reformat it as shown below. In the view below you'll need to add a class to each form element you want the datepicker to be thrown in for (i used the class 'datepicker'):

[image]

```
<%= simple_form_for @ionit_tank_input, url: controller_path_here, html: { multipart: true, method: :post, class: "whatever_css_styling_classes", role: "form"} do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.input :date1, as: :string, :placeholder => 'From (MM/DD/YYYY)', label: false, required: false, input_html: {class: "form-control form-input-colorss datepicker"} %>
            </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <%= f.input :date2,  as: :string, :placeholder => 'To (MM/DD/YYYY)', label: false, required: false, input_html: {class: "form-control form-input-colorss datepicker"} %>
         </div>

       <%= f.submit "See History", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %>
<% end %>
```

Add this script to your corresponding assets js file once you have the jquery datepicker installed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('input.datepicker').datepicker({
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        autoclose: true
    });
</script>
```

Then in your controller you can format the incoming date/time selected as needed.  The code below is to format it into a month/day/year but you can also add HH:MM just remember the user input coming in through your form will be a string so you need to use strptime to convert it.

```
from = DateTime.strptime("#{params[:ionit_tank_input][:date1]}", '%m/%d/%Y')
to = DateTime.strptime("#{params[:ionit_tank_input][:date2]}", '%m/%d/%Y')
to = to + 1.day
@inputs = @tank.ionit_tank_inputs.where(["created_at > ? and created_at < ?", from, to ])
```

@inputs is now your selection of info between those two days.  If you want you can use datetime.

Comment: thanks you, but I want to know, I have both date and hour condition, how do I define them? how do I know which type of condition to compare with?